# Batch variables remove line break

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

... a lot of batch script ...
IF ... a lot of batch script ...    

for /f "skip=2 delims== tokens=2" %%g in ('WMIC DATAFILE WHERE ^"Name^='!filePath!'^" GET Version /value') DO (
    set fileVersion=%%g
)

ECHO Version: !fileVersion!

set nightlyBuildFullPath=%2\Setups\Nightly Builds\!fileVersion!\Full\

ECHO FullPath: !nightlyBuildFullPath!
```

Result:

```
Version: 1.5.1810.202

FullPath: C:\test\Setups\Nightly Builds\1.5.1810.202
\Full\
```

I want to remove the linebreaks in the fileVersion variable because I have to build a path for later use. If I actually build the path string I have a linebreak in it, which corrupts my path.

Comment: For once, this is not really the fault of `cmd` or the batch script. `WMIC` puts strange end-of-line characters in its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ECHO Version: "%fileVersion:~0,-1%"
```

may assist your investigations...

Comment: Indeed. WMIC outputs lines ending with characters `0D 0D 0A` (hex) instead of the usual `0D 0A`. So `fileVersion` will contain an extra `0D` that you need to remove using this answer.

Comment: @Magoo thanks for your answer. That helped me and it works right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
for /f "skip=2 delims== tokens=2" %%g in ('WMIC DATAFILE WHERE ^"Name^='!filePath!'^" GET Version /value') DO (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%g") do set "fileVersion=%%#"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line into a file named veronly.ps1. Change the file name to the one you want to examine.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class 'CIM_DataFile' -Filter "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\psftp.exe'" | % { $_.Version }
```

Put the following into the .bat script file.

```
FOR /F %%v IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File .\veronly.ps1') DO (SET "THEVERSION=%%v")
ECHO %THEVERSION%
```

Answer (score -2):

REM :: As you use the commutator '/Value', you can use it to parse for command.

set myParams = WMIC DATAFILE WHERE ^"Name^='!filePath!'^" GET Version /value

for /f "**tokens=1-2 skip=1 delims==**" %%i in ('wmic /node:"%1" %myParams%') do **if "%%i" == "Version"** set "myVers=%%j"

REM :: DOS commands have the advantage of being able to run natively on all Microsoft systems. This can be useful when you have obsolete systems or when system or network security limits the execution of system commands.

Comment: Picture of text, wildly formatted text that might or might not be code, no explanation whatsoever..... I have no idea what this is meant to be. Would you like to [edit] and improve accordign to [answer]? Maybe take the [tour].

Comment: This info might help you to make the post look like you intend it to look, maybe after redeciding how it should look like....   https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help